# OpenCV 2.4 - Playing Video from file on OSX

Tags: python, c++, macos, opencv, computer-vision

I install Open CV and all the deps with `brew`

Following this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html#gsc.tab=0

I'm able to have it working with my webcam but unable to read a AVI or MP4 file. Every time, when I execute this command:

`ret, frame = cap.read()`, `frame` is `None`.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.12'`
```

Here is the script:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('drop.avi')

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read() # frame is ALWAYS None.
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

May be try reinstalling opencv with python and ffmpeg support

`brew install opencv --with-ffmpeg -v`

But before that install perian

http://www.perian.org/